# I'm trying to have a button that reverts the background colour to the gradient that it had when the page was loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying different things and haven't managed to find an answer to my question online. I have no idea how to make the button revert the background colour to the default colour that existed when the page was loaded.

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
var button = document.getElementById("resetbckg")

function setGradient() {
 body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, "
   + color1.value 
   +", "
   + color2.value 
   + ") ";

   css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
}

function reset() {
 document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, "
   + color1.value 
   +", "
   + color2.value 
   + ") ";
}

button.addEventListener("click", reset);
```

```css
body {
 font: "raleway", sans-serif;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: .5em;
 top: 15%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #3AC7E2, #A16DCE);
  }
```

```html
<input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
<input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
<div class="buffer col-12"></div>
<button id="resetbckg" onclick="reset()">Reset Background</button>
```

Comment: call your function inside `window.onload`

Comment: just add `window.onload = reset()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the body's background styling and revert to the style in the css rule, just set `document.body.style.background = ''`.

```js
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");

function setGradient() {
    document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, "
         + color1.value 
         +", "
         + color2.value 
         + ") ";
}

function reset() {
    document.body.style.background = "";
}
```

```css
body {
    font: "raleway", sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    top: 15%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #3AC7E2, #A16DCE);
}
```

```html
<input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
<input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
<div class="buffer col-12"></div>
<button onclick="setGradient()">Set Background</button><br/>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset Background</button>
```