# How to give users access to change the background color of html on whatever they like?

Tags: html, css

title. For example i put a button, and button says (press this button to change color from black to white). How to put that so a button can change the color of the background of the website?

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: sure whatever makes it work

Comment: You may refer to this. It can change the background in gradient.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618405/im-trying-to-have-a-button-that-reverts-the-background-colour-to-the-gradient-t/61618796#61618796

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there you go.  anything not make sense?

```js
function changeColor(){

var shabang = document.getElementById('shabang');

if (shabang.style.backgroundColor == "" ||shabang.style.backgroundColor=='white'){
    shabang.style.backgroundColor="black";
}else{
    shabang.style.backgroundColor ="white";
}
}
```

```css
html{
height:500px;
width:100%;
background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<html id='shabang'>
<button type='button' onclick="changeColor()">color me</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some text

```js
$( ".oldclassname" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass("newclass");
});
```

```css
.newclass{
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="oldclassname">button text</button>
```